# `new Error()` (which is a string in the console) isn't the same as `new Error().toString`

Tags: javascript

`new Error()` is an object with properties like name, message, stack, etc., but when displayed in the console, it's a string.

That makes sense; it's probably just being coerced to a string. But `new Error().toString()` doesn't return the same result. That doesn't make any sense, and the only way that can happen is if it is being coerced to a string like how for example the Date object is.

But that's not happening here, since it's not the same as the result of the `toString()` method. `new Date()` and `new Date().toString()` are the same. So do they have special rules for displaying them?

Comment: *Which* console? There is not standard for what consoles show - each implementation is free to show whatever is deemed most relevant when you log a value. Related, since it's all implementation dependent, some basic objects can be treated differently than just any other objects. Like, errors which are very much special kind and they might have custom rule defined for them.

Comment: A really good example is the difference between `console.log(someArray);` and `console.log(someArray.toString())`

Comment: @DanielA.White ...I literally just explained that. `Error` is an object, but when displayed in the console it's a string. The only way for that to be possible without some special rule is that it's being coerced to a string. But it's not. Because then `new Error()` and `new Error().toString()` would be the same. But they aren't.

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean? Like that is has a custom rule to display it? Could be possible but wouldn't make much sense

Comment: When you display an error in the console, it adds additional information like the location in the code where the error was created. So it displays "Error: <message> at <location>"

Comment: But coercing the error to a string just returns the message.

Comment: @VLAZ Chrome DevTools, Node => pretty much every console. It could be possible that there is another method above the toString method

Comment: I mean, there are. `@@toPrimitive` is there and Node also even has its own symbol `util.inspect.custom` that you can use to define custom inspection behaviour. With that said, you're still missing the fact that consoles do not have to follow any convention for all objects. The only direction they have is logging something that's supposed to be useful. And for error objects, the most useful thing is usually the stack trace.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't make sense to have different rules for displaying different types of objects? Just look at how the console displays DOM nodes.

Comment: @Bergi Well if the console would just coerce the error to a string, it would be much more customisable. DOM nodes are just colourful strings that are automatically collapsed.

Comment: If the console would just coerce every object to a string it would be much less useful than letting us dynamically expand and inspect them. And a console like node, which *does* print strings only, actually *is* fully customisable.

Comment: If it's being coerced to string by the console, it also has access to the original object. It could be two strings or when it's collapsed it shows its toString method and when it's expanded it also shows its trace property

Answer (score -1):

> the only way that can happen is if it is being coerced to a string

I don't think this part is true. For example:

```js
const log = (value) => {
    if (value instanceof Error) {
        // first block
    } else {
        // second block
    }
};
```

If you called the above function like `log(new Error())`, it would execute the first block. If you called it like `log(new Error().toString())`, it would execute the second block. These could have different results.

Comment: `new Error() instanceof Error` and `!(new Error().toString() instanceof Error)`. Very helpful.